# connect wireless access point to wireless modem

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, modem

At my office we have a wireless modem(D-Link DSL-2750U) and all the clients are connect to it wirelessly with a wireless lan card. at the next floor we have two pc(without wireless lan card) that I want to connect them to this network, I have a switch and a wireless access point(TP-Link TL-WA701ND).
my Question is that how can I connect the WAP to Modem?
I set the operation mode of WAP to client and add the MAC address of it in the table of wireless modem but the clients cant connect to the network.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just run cables from the two machines to the LAN ports on the `D-Link DSL-2750U`? If you're going to insist on using wifi, you'll want to use Bridge mode, or possibly WDS/Repeater, but Bridge mode will probably be more compatible one considering the differences in brand.

Answer (score 0):

This time the connection must be **wired** from the **access point** to the **switch** and then from the **switch** to the two **pc**, would be much easier.